# Calculations in a dataframe based on datetime values (with missing dates), without filling the dataframe with empty dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, missing-data

I have a dataframe similar to the one below and I want to calculate the sum of the `value` column for the last seven days. The problem is that there isn't necessarily a row for each day.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [2,3,7,14],
    'date': ['10/20/2005','10/22/2005','10/25/2005','10/27/2005']
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
value   date
    2   2005-10-20
    3   2005-10-22
    7   2005-10-25
    14  2005-10-27
```

What I would like to is something like

```
 df['value'].sum('Last 7 days')
 26
```

The solutions to the problem that I found were always about filling the df with the missing dates, using `.asfreq()` or `.reindex()`. Unfortunately, that is not an option for me since I have way too many classes that are each represented in a df like the above one. So filling the df up with the missing dates would create thousands and thousands of extra rows.

Is there a way to use `pd.Timedelta()` (or similar), where I can treat the missing days as zeros?

Comment: do you want to groupby the week or a rolling window of the last seven days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling has this intelligently built into the function for datetime based columns:

```
df.rolling('7d', on='date').sum()
```

Note that 10/27 and 10/20 are 8 days apart not 7 :)

And if you want to put it into another column:

```
df['sum'] = df.rolling('7d', on='date').sum()['value']
```

If you just want the final value:

```
df.rolling('7d', on='date').sum()['value'].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I have been looking for. This saves so much time.

Comment: Glad it is working. If it does solve your problem consider [marking it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so future users can find what they need more easily.

Comment: Is there a documentation for strings such as '7d' / '1w' / '1m' that pandas recognizes as datetime units?

Comment: There is a table [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) that goes over them about 30-40% down the page. Search for "Date Offset". It is worth noting that they don't always all work in every context.